# Programming terms - what's it called when you're continuously checking for the relevancy of an error message?

Tags: javascript, naming

The title may seem vague, let me elaborate.
I've made a form in javascript that when submitted validates the input fields.
When either of the 2 fields are invalid they get colored red.
What I want to add now is a listener that checks whether the user has inputted the correct values (in real time, ie. without clicking the submit button).
I need a good name for this function but can't come up with anything good...

Here's what I got so far:

checkRelevanceOfInvalidity()
checkStatusOfErrorMessage()

My current names for my functions:

function loadContentList()
function refreshGUI()
function addToContentList(title, rating)
function validateContent(title, rating)
function addContent()
function disableOption(pos)
function addEventListeners()
function init()
function devtest()

Comment: *"validate"* maybe? keep it simple.

Comment: Why do you need a new function? Just call your existing `validateContent` function whenever a field is changed, instead of when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: If i saw `checkRelevanceOfInvalidity` in someone's code i wouldn't know what it does by reading the name.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this. Naming matters; it makes code more human-readable and keeps organizational confusion to a minimum.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a validator factory

Comment: @RangerRick *"Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."* - http://stackoverflow.com/about. This question has no "right" answer.

Comment: @KevinB yeah I'll go with something simple like "validate" I think.. yeah my suggested names don't make any sense^^, it's getting late in front of the screen..

Comment: @JBentley won't do that because functionality-wise it wouldn't do what I want this script to do, but it's a good idea in other cases.

Comment: @Ryuji Could you possibly split it into different functions, for example, one that does the validation, and another that acts upon the result of he validation? that way the validation code is in one place and you just pass it a callback so that it performs a different action based what is passed as the callback. No sense in having two validate methods.

Comment: I've decided to call it validateInput (to differentiate it from validateContent), this seems to be the most clean and clear way for now, sorry for posting an "opinion-based question" but I thought it would have a general answer as the programming community already has standard established terms to denote the same "semantics" (ie. get, set, validation, events, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good method names are really important so its definitely worth thinking about.

It depends a bit on what valid means for each of the fields. If they are different then you could have something along the lines of:

- validTitle()
- validRating()

So, in the listener you would then do

```
if !validTitle()
    //highlight the title field
```

It may also be useful to have a general method that calls each one and displays a general error.

- searchFormIsValid()

The main listener function could be called

- checkSearchForm()

In Angular this would be a watcher, so maybe even watchSearchForm()

Its good to try and break things down as much as possible and have each method doing as small a thing as possible.